# Regex capture only items before CT

Tags: python, regex

Input

```
QT620.116T.00.01.0109.PX00.101920130742
```

Required Output:

```
QT620.116T.00.01.0109
```

My attempt (as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/EJFzHT/1))

```
.PX.*
```

Comment: Please post your attempt in the question as well (since if the referenced link dies, then the content is no longer available).

Comment: I do not think there is CT in the string.

Comment: and it seems you are looking for split?

Comment: You may want to escape `.` as it's a special character: `\.`

Comment: The only `ct` on this answer is in my name from the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a positive lookahead to match `.PX` after the desired match:

```
^.*?(?=\.PX)
```

- `^.*?` non-greedily matches everything upto the portion that is followed by `.PX` (`(?=\.PX)`)
- `(?=\.PX)` is *zero-width* positive lookahead, so does not get counted as output, only ensures the existence of `.PX` afterwards

**Example:**

```
In [55]: str_ = 'QT620.116T.00.01.0109.PX00.101920130742'

In [56]: re.search(r'^.*?(?=\.PX)', str_).group()
Out[56]: 'QT620.116T.00.01.0109'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the newer [**`regex`**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module, you could use a lookahead to split:

```
import regex as re

string = "QT620.116T.00.01.0109.PX00.101920130742"

(interesting, _) = re.split(r'(?V1)(?=\.PX\d+)', string)
print(interesting)
```

Which yields

```
QT620.116T.00.01.0109
```

The newer behaviour is enabled via `(?V1)`.